# What are the best practices for creating access tokens from Google Identity token for my custom services?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, google-oauth, google-identity

I am updating an old app to use Google authentication for sign in, it would be restricted with HD claim for a specific domain. I have no problem getting the ID token and verifying it using the google client library.

But now that I have authenticated, I need to authorize and generate an access token for my APIs.

**Should I use the verified ID token to generate a custom access token, since the ID token is proof of identity? Or is there a more correct way to handle it?**

**How should I handle refreshing?** My first thought would be to reverify an ID token from the client.

Here's some code if it helps to visualize my question.

```js
  const client = new OAuth2Client(process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID, process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET);
  try {
    const csrfCookie = req.cookies["csrf_token"];
    const csrfHeader = req.headers['csrf_token'];
    if (!csrfCookie) throw new UnauthorizedError("Missing CSRF token.");
    if (!csrfHeader) throw new UnauthorizedError("Missing CSRF token.");
    if (csrfCookie !== csrfHeader) throw new UnauthorizedError("Invalid CSRF Token.");
    if (!req.headers.idToken) throw new UnauthorizedError();

    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: req.headers.idToken,
      audience: process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    });


    const payload = ticket.getPayload();

    
    if(payload?.hd !== process.env.VERIFIED_DOMAIN)
      throw new UnauthorizedError();
      //todo: create or get account
      //todo: generate access token

   
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
```